# Difficulty in passing data from a location obtained using google maps place picker API and send it to a textView for the User to see the location

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I am developing a simple app that retrieves the location of a place using google place picker API but i am unable to retrieve the data and set it to a textView.Everything else works apart for retrieving the data.When overriding a method always use the @Overide annotation in order to ensure you override the method you intend to in order to avoid the below mistake

Below is an example of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText name;
    private EditText email;
    private TextView date;
    private TextView location;


    private Button Submit,Select;
    private String NAME;    // stores name value
    private  String EMAIL; // stores email value
    private String DATE;    // stores  date value

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;

    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNameID);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEmailID);

        NAME = name.getText().toString();
        EMAIL = email.getText().toString();

        location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationtxt);

        date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSelectDate);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                int month = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
                int day = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                month = month+1;

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight, dateSetListener,year,month,day);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                String result  = day  +"/" +month +"/"+year;
                date.setText(result);
            }
        };
        DATE = date.getText().toString();


        Select = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SelectLocationbtn);
        Select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

                try {

                    Intent intent = builder.build(MainActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


        Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Submitbtn);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

    }
    protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

        if(requestCode==PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){

            if(resultCode== RESULT_FIRST_USER){
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, MainActivity.this);
                String name = String.format("Place: %s",place.getName());
                location.setText(name);

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the captial `O` in `OnActivityResult()`;

It's a good idea to use the @Override annotation in order to ensure you're overriding the method you intend to:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if(requestCode==PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){

        if(resultCode== RESULT_FIRST_USER){
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, MainActivity.this);
            String name = String.format("Place: %s",place.getName());
            location.setText(name);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so so . much